# Merge two EPS Files into one

Tags: floats, eps, subfloats

I want to use sub-figures in my paper. I have used `subfig` package in LaTeX and `fig1a`, `fig1b` as my sub-figures. However, the journal compiles the files itself and only accepts one file for each figure, and I must merge the two `eps` files into one, and use the ordinary `figure` package. How can I merge the two `eps` files such that the two sub-figures near each other look like when I used `subfig` package.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could make the figure in a separate file (possibly with `\documentclass{standalone}`), then include the result into your manuscript. This would allow you to use `subfig` and keep the result you already have.